# ¿Cómo evitar inyección de sql en asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Para evitar ataques de este tipo, ya que son muy frecuentes hoy en día. ¿Qué debo hacer en mi código para evitar la inyección SQL?

Comment: Para evitar inyección SQL debes hacer uso de **consultas preparadas**, a las cuales les debes **pasar parámetros**.
Podrías especificar más sobre tu código quizás para ayudarte a blindarlo, o por otra parte investigar más sobre las consultas preparadas en asp.net.

Comment: El caso es que yo trabajo con linq y C# en Visual Studio 2015, y el asisten de roles de .Net y como está parte es algo delicado a nivel de seguridad, quiero saber la magnitud del problema cuando se llegará a presentar y que la aplicación web este lista para este tipo de situación

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo importante para evitar la inyección sql es que los parámetros de la consulta que utilices no se concatenen en el texto de la consulta así:

```
var comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from Tabla where nombre = " + txtnombre.Text);
```

sino que se agreguen como parametros sql así:

```
var comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from Tabla where nombre = ?");
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("nombre", txtnombre.Text));
```

de esta manera ADO.net maneja la seguridad de los textos ingresados como parámetro y evitas que se inyecte sql no deseado en tu aplicación.

Answer (score 3):

Lo mejor es utilizar Parámetros, de esta manera no podrán manipular  tus Querys a través de los Controles, aca dejo un ejemplo:

`Es te método es  más recomendable para evitar inyecciones de SQL.`

```
        private void AntiInyecc()
    {
       SqlConnection conexion= new SqlConnection("TuCadena de Conexion");

        string SqlString = "Insert Into tbl_Datos (Folio,Dia,Nombre) Values" +
              "(@folio,@dia,@nomb)";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlString, conexion))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@folio", lblID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dia", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomb", textBox2.Text);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

se recomienda usar procedimientos almacenados, pero en caso no quieras usarlo en .NET desde el VS2008 ya existe un nuevo concepto llamado [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) el cual te permite realizar consultas desde el mismo lenguaje de programación con una sintaxis similar a los "Selects" que realizas en SQLServer pero con la misma seguridad de los procedimientos almacenados.

Saludos!

Comment: Los procedimientos almacenados no son suficientes para prevenir la inyección SQL.  LINQ sí es seguro porque parametriza los datos, pero podría ser inseguro si se combina con un método inseguro (p.e.  con un procedimiento almacenado que genere la sentencia dinámicamente)

Comment: Entonces el nivel de seguridad es 50%?

Answer (score 0):

gracias @CarlosR93 que buen dato la verdad me ayudaste a encontrar el camino para solucionar un problema de llave foranea, de verdad muy agradecido.

Comment: No añadas “gracias” como respuesta. En cambio, vota a favor de las respuestas que encuentres útiles. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/340970)