# como se ingresan los datos correctos de un DateTimePicker por from de c# a sql

Tags: c#, visual-studio

hol buenas me dirian a que se debe este error al intentar ingresar datos desde un form a sql

pasa que intento hacer un simple ingreso de los datos pero el error habla de que no se pudo hacer una conversion de datos a caracter string pero nose a que se refiera exactamente.

cualquier sugerencia lo agradeceria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo

```
string idCliente = textBox_identificadorCliente.Text;
                string nombre = textBox_NombreCliente.Text;
                string primerApellido = textBox_PrimerApellido.Text;
                string segundoApellido = textBox_segundoApellido.Text;
                char genero;
                if (comboBox_genero.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    genero = 'M';

                }
                else
                {
                    genero = 'F';

                }
                
                DateTime fechaNacimiento = dateTimePicker_fechaNacimiento.Value;
                DateTime fechaIngreso = dateTimePicker_fechaIngreso.Value;

                string consulta = "INSERT INTO Cliente (IdCliente, Nombre, PrimerApellido, SegundoApellido, FechaNacimiento, Genero, FechaIngreso) " +
               "values('"+idCliente+"', '"+nombre+"', '"+primerApellido+"', '"+segundoApellido+"', '"+dateTimePicker_fechaNacimiento.Value+"', '"+genero+"', '"+dateTimePicker_fechaIngreso.Value+"')";

                try
                {

                   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexionMaestra.conectar);
                   
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("La persona fue agregada exitosamente");



                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Error : "+ e.ToString());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Usa el método ToString() para darle el formato universal a la fecha y poderla enviar como string:

   ```
   string consulta = "INSERT INTO Cliente (IdCliente, Nombre, PrimerApellido, SegundoApellido, FechaNacimiento, Genero, FechaIngreso) " +
                   "values('"+idCliente+"', '"+nombre+"', '"+primerApellido+"', '"+segundoApellido+"', '"+dateTimePicker_fechaNacimiento.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+"', '"+genero+"', '"+dateTimePicker_fechaIngreso.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+"')";
   ```
2. Es una buena práctica usar Parameters en tu query de esta forma puedes especificar el tipo de datos y evitar la inyección SQL.

```
    string consulta = @"INSERT INTO Cliente (IdCliente, Nombre, PrimerApellido, SegundoApellido, FechaNacimiento, Genero, FechaIngreso)
                        values(@idCliente,@nombre,@primerApellido,@segundoApellido,@fechaNacimiento,@genero, @fechaIngreso)";
    
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexionMaestra.conectar);
    
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fechaNacimiento", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = dateTimePicker_fechaNacimiento.Value });
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fechaIngreso", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = dateTimePicker_fechaIngreso.Value });
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[¿Cómo evitar inyección de sql en asp.net?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/85750/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-inyecci%C3%B3n-de-sql-en-asp-net)